# PHP multiple string replace exclude string inside braces

Tags: php

```
$str = "PHP is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed for {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming language";
$search = array('php','for','english');
$replace = array('{{Java}}','{{to}}','{{italian}}');

$new_str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

how can we exclude the string inside {{ ... }}. and text replaced to be in {{...}} such that the output should be

*// tobe "{{Java}} is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed {{to}} {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming {{italian}}"*

DONE

Edited from ankit singh answer bellow

```
<?php
$str = "PHP is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed for {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming language";
$replaceWith = [
    'php'=>'{{Java}}',
    'for'=>'{{to}}',
    'language'=>'{{italian}}',
];
$new_str = $str;
foreach ($replaceWith as $key => $value) {
    $pattern = sprintf('/{{[^}]+}}(*SKIP)(*F)|%s/', preg_quote($key, '/'));
$new_str = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $new_str);
}

print_r($new_str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array to replace string

```
$str = "PHP is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed for {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming language";
$replaceWith = [
    'php'=>'{{Java}}',
    'for'=>'{{to}}',
    'language'=>'{{italian}}',
];
$new_str = $str;
foreach ($replaceWith as $key => $value) {
    $new_str = str_ireplace($key, $value, $new_str);
}

print_r($new_str);
```

Comment: How to prevent replace text inside braces {{scripting languange}}  ? that code change text become {{scripting {{italian}}}}..